# Big Thank You for All Your Help!

Tags: discussion

I have just finished self-studying my way through *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer. I read every word, and solved every problem (well over 1k). I couldn't possibly have done it without all your help here on Stats.SE. Especially big shout-out to whuber and Spätzle. Thank you!

Comment: Exciting! 1k problems are a lot, and over that is more than a lot!

Comment: That's quite an effort. Where next? Volume I of Kendall and Stuart? :) ... I did so many exercises out of that.

Comment: @Glen_b What's next is *Linear Models in R, 2nd Ed.,* by Julian J. Faraway. I'm basically self-studying my way to a B.S. in Statistics, and I'm loosely following Virginia Tech's curriculum, if not their book choices. After Linear Models, I want to do analysis and design of experiments.

Comment: Studying linear models is a good choice at that point, yes.